# JavaScript Get Image cross PHP file

Tags: javascript

I created a PHP file, which give back an image location.
for example:
https://www.example.com/api/example.php Its give back this:
https://www.example.com/image1.png

Its okey.
But I need to read the example.php and GET the image location (so the https:// www dot example dot com/image1.png) and display on my site with Javascript.

```
var wheelImageName   = "url/image1.png";

function begin()



{

surface = document.getElementById(canvasId);


if (surface.getContext) 
{
    wheel = new Image();
    wheel.onload = initialDraw;     
    wheel.src = wheelImageName;
}
}
```

This is the code now, My question is, how to modify this, to read the target image url from the example.php.

Thanks!

Comment: Go read up on AJAX. That's how you can communicate back and forth with your server.

Comment: @MikeC I know this, I have the open send things because I use it to get back data from another PHP file, but here I need to the get back the image URL and than put into the image source. Thats why I asked. wheel.src must be = with the GET data, and I dont know how to do.

Comment: If you know how to use AJAX to make a request to your server then you know how to get the image URL. If you know how to get the image URL, you know how to assign it to `wheel.src`.

Comment: But I dont know how to use ajax, Its the 2nd time when I need to use, and I hope its the last time. 
`
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = ajaxCallback;

   if (determinedGetUrl)
   {
    xhr.open('GET', determinedGetUrl, true);
    xhr.send('');
    

   }`

Comment: Then look up how to use AJAX. There's a massive number of tutorials on the subject. In fact, the "duplicate" question shows you how to use it.

Comment: It doesnt help for me. :c, but I tried so many ways to fix it. Its give back always nothink, and I dont know how to debug javascript applications, its not like PHP...